# Как буферизировать изображение без отображения при загрузке с интернета?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Как можно сделать чтобы например при открытии активити все нужные изображения с интернета скачивались
1 раз, а потом можно было в любой момент их открыть без загрузки повторно?

Comment: Такое делает почти любая либа для картинок. С той или иной степенью гибкости, очевидности и удобства. Попробуйте картинки отображать через Glide - оно должно будет по умолчанию как раз на диск картинки записать.

Answer (score 0):

Получив изображение, вы можете его сохранить, затем обращаясь к нему

```
private void SavePicture(ImageView iv) {
    OutputStream fOut = null;
    try {
        File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/..../background.jpg"); 
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut); // сохранять картинку в jpeg-формате с 85% сжатия.
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(),  file.getName()); // регистрация в фотоальбоме
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```